# Error working with structs and pointer arrays: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c, pointers, arrays, struct

```
#define STRMAX 50

struct Person {
    char sName[STRMAX];
    int iAge;
};
typedef struct Person PERSON;

int main() {
    PERSON *personen[1];
    personen[0]->sName = "Pieter";
    personen[0]->iAge = 18;

    return 0;
}
```

This code generates an error on `personen[0]->sName = "Pieter";` saying *incompatible types in assignment*. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want an array of pointers. Try
`PERSON personen[1];`

And like others have said, use the strcpy function!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to assign arrays. Use `strcpy` to copy the string from one array to the other.

...`sName` is an array of chars while "Pieter" is a `const char*`. You cannot assign the latter to the former. The compiler is always right :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
PERSON *personen[1];
```

to

```
PERSON personen[1];
```

and  use strcpy to copy the string.

```
strcpy(personen[0]->sName,"Pieter");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above but I figured it was also important to include the "why"

```
int a;      // is an integer
int *b;     // pointer to an integer must be malloced (to have an array)
int c[];    // pointer to an integer must also be malloced (to have an array)
int d[5];   // pointer to an integer bu now it is initialized to an array of integers
```

to get b and c from simple pointers and give them memory to match d use the following to give them memory space

```
b = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

where it casts the pointer returned from malloc to an int pointer, and creates a memory block of 5 times the size of an integer (thus it will hold 5 integers like d)